# GAE Standard Environment keep getting 503

Tags: google-app-engine

In past 3 - 4 days, I have been getting 503 whenever I deploy in Standard Environment. This happens very frequently, usually about 3 hours after new deployment

I checked https://status.cloud.google.com/ and there doesn't seem to be known incident. However, on October 6th, there seems to be an incident that sounds like the issue I'm facing right now https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/20007

Can somebody help guide us what to do?

Comment: Can you share the logs please ?

Comment: It will be best to open a ticket with the support team [1] so that they investigate your project and inspect your instance to confirm whether or not your issue is related to that incident.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/